# Passing table variable into dynamic SQL 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to run a dynamic sql which uses table variable created in the scope of the parent. How do I pass table variable into dynamic sql in SQL2008 ?

Comment: Given the general nature of your question, perhaps you'll be well-served by this general exposition on dynamic sql? http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an end-end example:

```
-- Define a custom TABLE type
CREATE TYPE IntegerTableType AS TABLE (ID INTEGER);

-- Fill a var of that type with some test data
DECLARE @MyTable IntegerTableType
INSERT @MyTable VALUES (1),(2),(3)

-- Now this is how you pass that var into dynamic statement
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM @MyTable', 
    N'@MyTable IntegerTableType READONLY', 
    @MyTable
```